# Смена Activity через Fragment

Tags: java, android

Есть класс, который наследуется от класса `Fragment`. Использую его для смены `activity` с помощью `sidebar`'a. На этом фрагмента размещена кнопка, которая должна менять `activity`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookCreate.class);
            startActivity(SecAct);
        }
    });
```

Но, поскольку мой класс наследуется не от `AppCompatActivity`, я не могу использовать метод `getApplicationContext()`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если кнопка во фрагменте то:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SecAct = new Intent(getActivity(), BookCreate.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(SecAct);
        }
    });
```